# GDI+ saving image only once in the loop

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am new to this library.
I want to convert all the gif files to tif. Following is my code. it is only saving 1st time ,there after it is throwing status = 2(invalid parameters).
please help me

```
    do {
        if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {

            wstring str(ffd.cFileName);
            str = gifDir1 + str;
            const wchar_t *filename = str.c_str();           

            Image *image = new Image(ffd.cFileName);

            wstring str2(ffd.cFileName);
            wstring::size_type found = str2.find(L".gif");
            str2.replace(found, str2.length(), L".tif");
            str2 = tifDir + str2;
            const wchar_t *dstfilename = str2.c_str();               

            stat = image->Save(dstfilename, &encoderClsid, NULL);

            if (stat == Ok)
                printf("File was saved successfully\n");
            else
                printf("Failure: stat = %d\n", stat);

            delete image;

        }

    } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `std::string::replace` is the number of characters to replace, not the length of the string.  As a result, you probably have a buffer overrun which is messing up other memory (e.g., like the `encoderClsid`).